# Can a nRF24L01+ chip work alone? (i.e. without Arduino borad)

Tags: arduino, nrf24l01, esp8266

I have a prototype based on the ESP8266 wifi tranceiver as a standalone module, without any Arduino borad.

It works fine, but I have heard that the nRF24L01+ chip is less power consuming.

After some online research, I think there is no possibilities to embeed a program on the nRF24L01+, as it has [no memory](https://www.nordicsemi.com/kor/Products/2.4GHz-RF/nRF24L01P).

I just wanted to check in this forum if I am right or wrong.

(If I am right, there is no point considering the nRF24L01+ as I should also power the Arduino board)

Comment: nRF24L01+ is a Transceiver IC. It will transmit the data fed to it. You will need an intelligent device to control it. Be it Arduino or some other MCU

Comment: You certainly *don't* need an "Arduino board", but you *will* need a microcontroller of some sort. Personally, I use an 8-bit PIC, one of the lower-power PIC16LFxxx range.

Comment: Right! But the nRF24L01+ deep sleep under 1uA and a ATtiny85 deep sleep under 1 mA / compared to an ESP8266 deep sleep at 18mA. Then, ATtiny+nRF24L01+ would be much less power consuming than ESP8266? Am I right?

Comment: @VincentLê have you checked the functionality that is available in deep sleep for each of the components? Maybe deep sleep on ESP8266 means that there is still a connection being held or something else, where as on the nRF24L01+ it might mean that it is just a dead chip basically until woken up by some external event (at 1µA very likely). If you don't need the provided functionality of the ESP then it's probably a poor choice for your application.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure of the deep sleep functionalities of the ESP8266, but for a very low power tranceiver, my calculations (and according to different weblogs) show that a NRF24L01+ and ATtiny85 would be far more interesting thant esp8266. Now, the esp8266 is great for a first prototype!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nRF24L01+ is indeed just a tranceiver IC with no embedded firmware you can modify.

It has some capability to reduce the amount of work needed by the application controller (which can be any MCU, you can build your own ultra low power design if an Arduino is too power hungry), but the protocol stack has to be implemented there.

Maybe you want to take a look at the nRF24LE1 - which has integrated flash (16kB) and MCU (8-bit), but I don't think it's possible to fit a wifi stack in there.

There are similar solutions from [TI](http://www.ti.com/lsds/ti/wireless_connectivity/embedded_wi-fi/overview.page) and others around, which might be worth a look. Wireless stuff is advancing very fast these days, so I won't post any more specific stuff, as it will be obsolete on Monday.

Comment: Thank you. You pointed the right problem here: ther is no wifi stack available for a nRF24L01+ solution.